Adobe Digital Editions: connection error with xebook
I cannot open books from xebook, and the popup text reads "Connection Error Detected: Digital Editions could not connect to the fulfillment server"
Books from other servers have always worked fine.
I've already deleted and resinstall it, changing my ID too.
I'm on Windows 7, ADE 4.5
